# Why is my fancybox plugin not working for my youtube link?

Tags: jquery, youtube, fancybox, lightbox

I cannot figure out why it isn't loading, it seems the same as fancybox's youtube link on their demo homepage.  Plus, all the other fancyboxes on the page work.  It's [here](http://nicolaelvin.com/other_stuff.php) and the one that isn't working is everybody's smoking video.

Here is my html:

```
<li class="portfolio-tn">
   <a class="fancybox" title="A video I made whilst I was giving up smoking. Unfortunately the video tape reel got damaged and the film quality isn't great. " href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/NXzSX5Cbebw">
       <img alt="thumbnail of Everybody's Smoking Video" src="images/assets/other_stuff/smokingvideo_thumbnail.png">
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and JS here - otherwise, this question becomes useless for future generations once the problem has been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: yeah - arguably, it *has* become the generic name. (I removed the comment, it's clear now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use an `iframe` element to embed video from a different domain.

The [fancybox docs](http://fancybox.net/howto) say that you can achieve this using one of two ways:

```
<a href="http://www.example?iframe">This goes to iframe</a>
```

or

```
<a class="iframe" href="http://www.example">This goes to iframe</a>
```

Comment: ahh that's wonderful, thank you.  I obviously wasn't paying as much attention to the documentation as I thought.

Answer (score 0):

for fancybox 2 and video you will need to add

```
<a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opj24KnzrWo">My Video</a>
```

for iframe

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://osx86.transformnews.com/">My Iframe</a>
```

[example](http://wordpress.transformnews.com/plugins/myfancybox-simple-fancybox-implementation-for-wordpress-4)