# New Youtube Link breaks site

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fullpage.js

Our website uses both fancybox(/media) and fullPage.js. When  I try to replace a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5SCbkuz5Dc) on the site, it breaks both. Also, when I update the video OR the image, it breaks the JS on the site.

It works fine, however, on a local test or [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/828vxdoz/) (line 83)

```
<div class="slide broadcast">
    <section class="intro creativetop">We can communicate your message across any medium: <br>Broadcast Media such as TV. . .</section>
    <div class=ccontent>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5SCbkuz5Dc" title="Helm Paint and Supply">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/l5SCbkuz5Dc/0.jpg" height="150" width="250">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvBnMjbsA7E" title="Chag's Fishing">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/MvBnMjbsA7E/0.jpg" height="150" width="250">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox-media" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP3JKEPiMQQ" title="Campbell Cabinets">
                    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/hP3JKEPiMQQ/3.jpg?time=1406563337365" height="150" width="250">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class=ccontent>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xz8MBIobbPI" title="Hickory Small Animal Hospital">
                    <img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/xz8MBIobbPI/3.jpg?time=1401724792643" height="150" width="250">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QuHQ0HCQlKQ" title="Chag's Archery">
                    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/QuHQ0HCQlKQ/0.jpg" height="150" width="250">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="fancybox-media" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMEebTZfE-k" title="Jefferson Feed">
                    <img src="https://i1.ytimg.com/vi/aMEebTZfE-k/2.jpg?time=1402693795205" height="150" width="250">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how well your users' browsers deal with problems in the template, it may be due to malformed HTML. You should declare classes as strings: in other words, `class=ccontent` should become `class="ccontent"`. I think you missed a closing div too.

You can use http://www.dirtymarkup.com/ to catch some of these errors.

Once you've cleaned up the template, run through the instructions on http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/, and make sure to load the following dependencies on the page:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
```

Finally, attach Fancybox to your `class="fancybox-media"` elements:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox-media").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I cleaned up my sloppy (old) code and broke it even worse, ended up having to restore the site with an original version stored on an older computer. I changed the Youtube links there and it worked. Maybe it's my version of Filezilla or Notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this link](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/); within it, it indicated that you need to run "FancyBox" on the backend in order to show media from: Youtube, Vimeo, Metacafe, Dailymotion, Twitvid, Twitpic, or Instagram.

I assume this is due to the browser restricting iframe access from Javascript, so FancyBox probably scrapes the content on the backend and builds out a custom frame that it then sends to the frontend in order to get around this constraint. (Just a theory, I may be wrong.)

## FancyBox Responsive Youtube Demo:

```html
<iframe src="http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancybox-download/responsive-youtube-videos/fancybox-youtube.html" style="width:100%;height:100%;display:block;position:fixed;"></iframe>
```

If you'd like step by step instructions on how to build a response Youtube player like this then check out [this tutorial on "Responsive Youtube Videos with FancyBox"](http://webdesignandsuch.com/responsive-youtube-videos-with-fancybox/) *(it isn't much of a tutorial, but he at least gives you a good example along with some code to play with.)*

Also, check out [this StackOverFlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704225/why-is-my-fancybox-plugin-not-working-for-my-youtube-link), posted by a user who was experiencing similar difficulties.